# Json returning an error when trying to load Japense characters in Python?

Tags: python, json

I am using a json config that is loaded in Python, which then uses selenium to fill in boxes just testing around. However when I try and find Japense characters by visible text on a drop down menu it returns,

```
  File "tronio.py", line 38, in <module>
    t1config = json.load(open("tasks/task1.json"))
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 549: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the code that loads json. I thing that the problem is the codec you’d choosen: should be something like decode("utf-8")

Comment: @SergeyBelash Decode or Encode?

Answer (score 2):

specify the encoding when opening the file

```
open("tasks/task1.json", encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: I seem to be getting this now Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tronio.py", line 1220, in <module>
    task1()
  File "tronio.py", line 265, in task1
    selectprefecture.select_by_value(t1config['state'])
  File "C:\Users\ninja_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\select.py", line 87, in select_by_value
    raise NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate option with value: %s" % value)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with value: 岩手県

Comment: I double checked IDs, and the select menu is based on option values

Comment: I'm pretty sure it still does not understand the characters

Comment: I think it does, but it doesn't find the element with said name on the page.

Comment: The said element is on the page @Joost and it works in English

Comment: The link is private @Joost

Comment: You can't really expect us to answer this with only one traceback as all available information. If you want more help, post a new question with at least some sample html so we know what to look for.